# c++ openmp for loop max reduction value during interim of loop execution

Tags: c++, multithreading, max, openmp, reduction

When computing a max reduction inside a parallel for loop what is the value of the max reduction variableat intermediate times during the loop's execution? Is it the max only for a particular thread or is it the max of all threads?

The reason I ask is that I want to use the current max value inside the loop to perform a calculation and I want it to be the current maximum of all the threads not just the thread that is executing the loop.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    double randomarray[10];
    //initialize the random array

    double outputarray[10];
    double currentmax = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(max:currentmax)
    for( i=0;i<10; i++) {

        if(randomarray[i] > currentmax)
        {
            currentmax = randomarray[i];   
        }

        output[i]=randomarray[i]/currentmax;
        // is this current max for the currently 
        // executing thread or all threads?
    }

}
```

Comment: Your current code is too simple and is memory bandwidth bound.

Comment: @Zboson I have a specific problem that I'm trying to solve where I need to know the current maximum before the global maximum has been computed; therefore, your suggestion to do two passes has nothing to do with the problem I'm trying to solve. If you know a better solution that is not "memory bandwidth bound" please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it the max only for a particular thread or is it the max of all threads?

It's a "per thread" private value within OpenMP parallel region.

The following code snippet might implement what you want to do, but it doesn't feel so meaningful.

```c
#pragma omp parallel for
for( i=0;i<10; i++) {
  double local_max;

  #pragma omp critical
  {
    if(randomarray[i] > currentmax)
    {
      currentmax = randomarray[i];   
    }
    local_max = currentmax;
  }

  output[i]=randomarray[i]/local_max;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of the reduction variable is undefined in the construct that uses the `reduction` close and differs among threads. There are private copies of the variable for each thread. You will have to re-think your parallelization.

From the OpenMP 4 specifications:

> For parallel and worksharing constructs, a private copy of each list
>   item is created, one for each implicit task, as if the private clause
>   had been used. ... The private copy is then initialized as specified
>   above. At the end of the region for which the reduction clause was
>   specified, the original list item is updated by combining its original
>   value with the final value of each of the private copies, using the
>   combiner of the specified reduction-identifier.

Answer (score 0):

The other responses made it clear that the openmp max reduction does not provide the functionality that I require. So I found another way of implementing it by means of an atomic max operation defined below:

```
inline double __sync_fetch_and_max_double(double* address, double val) {
  int64_t* address_as_int64 = (int64_t*)address;
  int64_t old = *address_as_int64, assumed;
  do {
    assumed = old;
    double assumed_double = *((double*)&assumed);
    double min = (val > assumed_double) ? val : assumed_double;
    old = __sync_val_compare_and_swap(address_as_int64, assumed,
                                      *((int64_t*)&min));
  } while (assumed != old);
  return *((double *)&old);
}
```

Then modify the code from the question to compute the max  and store in a single variable shared between all the threads. Since the function is atomic the value of the variable always has a unique value, which is the current max across all the threads.

The modified code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    double randomarray[10];
    //initialize the random array

    double outputarray[10];
    double currentmax = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for( i=0;i<10; i++) {

        __sync_fetch_and_max_double(&currentmax,randomarray[i]);   

        output[i]=randomarray[i]/currentmax; //max among all threads

    }

}
```

Comment: There are many difference ways to do this. E.g. you don't have to do use atomic or critical. You could do a first pass to find the max value for each thread and then communicate the values to each thread to correct and then do a second pass. This is what I do with the prefix sum. But what you're currently doing is memory bandwidth bound anyway (so is the prefix sum) so it's not very interesting. What are you ultimately trying to achieve?